# how to take a dataframe as an input and manipulate based on a function in R

Tags: r, dataframe

lets say I have the following df

```
year    score
2020     51
2020     10
2019     82
2019     73
```

and lets say I have the following function in R

```
sumOfNumbers <- function (sum){
    firstNumber = with(df, sum(as.numeric(substring(df$score, 1, 1))))
    secondNumber = with(df, sum(as.numeric(substring(df$score, 1, 1))))
    return (c(firstNumber,secondNumber))
}
```

where the function returns the sum of the first numbers (i.e. **5** +**1** +**8**+**2**) and the sum of the second numbers (i.e. **1** +**0** +**2**+**3**. This calculates for the whole df.

and now I want to filter by the year

```
year2020 <- subset(df, year %in% "2020")
```

But when I try inputting the filtered df into the function I get an error (understandably because the function is for the whole df). How can I use the function that calculates the sum and the filtered df?

result -> for 2020 the first number should add up to 6 and thee second number should add up to 1

Comment: Add an argument to the function to allow you to pass an arbitrary dataframe to it.  If you make the data frame argument the first argument to the function, you could easily incorporate it in a pipe.

Comment: I tried doing that. I tried using data.frame(sum) as an argument and it didn't work. Any thoughts on how to fix that?

Comment: Change your function signature to `function(df, sum)` and then call it with `sumOfNumbers(df %>% filter(Year== 2020))` or `df %>% filter(Year == 2020) %>% sumOfNumbers()`.  I'm not clear how you're calling your function, nor the purpose of your `sum` argument.  The `sum` argument might be superfluous.

Comment: 1. I think you are using *substring()* function wrong. How it is writting, it is taking the first digit of every number in the column. 2. You dont need to call sum as a input, it is a called function inside yours. 3. You need to add another ending ) to return. Also you should specify df as an input.